# how to change text and icon together on a single click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to play a video when the user clicks the play icon. When user clicks on the "play" icon or "watch video" text the video should start to play and "play" icon and "watch video" text should change to "pause" icon and "pause video" text respectively.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
var btn = document.getElementById("watch");

function playVid() {
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    btn.classList.toggle("fa-pause-circle");
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause Video";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    btn.classList.toggle("fa-play-circle");
    btn.innerHTML = "Watch Video";
  }

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<video id="myVideo">
         <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbHIDVVTSNA" type="video/mp4"> 
         Indian Spice Video
    </video>

<h3 onclick="playVid()" id="watch">
  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Watch Video
</h3>
```

When the user clicks first time to play icon video is started to play and font changes to "pause video" and icon are also change but the proper icon is not shown after 3-4 click icon gets disappear.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to toggle the class you want to remove one class and add the other. You can do this with the replace function When you toggle the class will be added or removed based on the fact if the element has the class already or not.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
var btn = document.getElementById("watch");

function playVid() {
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    btn.classList.replace("fa-play-circle", "fa-pause-circle");
    btn.querySelector('.button_text').innerText = "Watch Video";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    btn.querySelector('.fa').classList.replace("fa-pause-circle", "fa-play-circle");
    btn.querySelector('.button_text').innerText = "Watch Video";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<video id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbHIDVVTSNA" type="video/mp4"> 
  Indian Spice Video
</video>

<h3 onclick="playVid()" id="watch">
  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span class="button_text">Watch Video</span>
</h3>
```

Comment: thank you, now icon is not disappearing after some click but icon is not visible. instead of that some box is appearing.

Comment: This line 'btn.innerHTML="Pause Video";' will remove the 'i' tag

Comment: @karuna I've added snippet, you can go with that.

Comment: @karuna Try with `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` so your html inside of the btn is not deleted.Updated my answer.

Comment: @karuna Also changed it so you actually change the `i` element instead of the `h3` element when changing the classes .

Comment: @MarkBaijens this "textContent" also removes the 'i' tag.

Comment: @I see, wrapping the text in a span and select that for chaning would be the easiest options. Otherwise you need to iterate over the childnodes, check if it's the correct (text) node and then change it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
   var btn = document.getElementById("watch");

   function playVid(){
       if(vid.paused){
           vid.play();
           btn.querySelector('.fa').classList.replace('fa-play-circle', 'fa-pause-circle');
           btn.querySelector('span').innerHTML="Pause Video";
       }
       else{
           vid.pause();
           btn.querySelector('.fa').classList.replace('fa-pause-circle', 'fa-play-circle');
           btn.querySelector('span').innerHTML = "Watch Video";
       }

   }
```

```html
<video id="myVideo">
       <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Indian Spice Video
   </video>

<h3 onclick="playVid()" id="watch">
   <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true" ></i> 
   <span>Watch Video</span>
</h3>
```

What did you miss:

- Instead of toggle, you should have used replace on classList.
- The class should be replaced in 'i' tab not instead of the button itself.
- This line "btn.innerHTML="Pause Video";" was removing all the inner HTML in button including your icon as well.

Comment: Always provide a clear explanation about your answer

Comment: @Ramesh Updated the post with some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

As the answers mentioned in the above replace is one of the options. Also here I demonstrate to remove and add classes of `play` and `pause` icons. The line `btn.innerHTML` replacement of your code initially removes the `<i>` tag from your element. **So the `replace` is not possible here.** The following is a working demo to add and remove the classes for `PLAY` and `PAUSE` clicks.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
var btn = document.getElementById("watch");

function playVid() {
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    btn.classList.remove('fa-play-circle');    
    btn.classList.add('fa-pause-circle');
    btn.classList.add('fa');
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause Video";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    btn.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
    btn.classList.add('fa-play-circle');
    btn.classList.add('fa');
    btn.innerHTML = "Watch Video";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<video id="myVideo">
         <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
         Indian Spice Video
    </video>

<h3 onclick="playVid()" id="watch">
  <i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Watch Video
</h3>
```

Comment: So, in this case, you don't need 'i' inside h3 just add the classes 'fa fa-play-circle' in h3 itself initially.

Comment: @Prawinsoni But there is a formal way to use font awesome icons

Comment: Ok, then 'i' tag should not be removed and class should be replaced in 'i' tag instead of h3.